# Get a previously defined constant's value in the same abstract class definition

Tags: php, constants, abstract-class

I'm trying to create an abstract class that would save a few strings. I want each of the constants to have the value of the previous constant and some other addition. For example, something like this:

```
abstract class Test
{
    const a = "a",
            b = "ab",
            c = "abc";
}
```

I don't want to repeat everything twice, so when I want to change `a` for example, I need to change it in each of the values. I want it to use the previous value in the next constant so when I change something, it will all be changed by one value. Is something like that possible? I tried `this::a` but it didn't work, and I couldn't think of any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Constant expression support was added in PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> It is possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric and string literals and/or constants in context of a class constant.

This way, you can do:

```
const a = "a",
      b = self::a . "b",
      c = self::a . "bc";
```

You access `const` inside classes with `self`

Comment: The page won't load after I do something like that.

Comment: @OmerAviv [How so ?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/769cb8e9e59165b0ba4ff187bd4b605c072f360c) It's perfectly fine for 5.6+ as I said in my answer